# How to print star pattern using only 2 for loops

Tags: c

I want to print this pattern [half diamond shape]

```
  *
 * *
* * *
```

by using 2 for loops
its really easy to print this pattern by using 3 for loops

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
  clrscr();
  int i,j,k;
  for(i=0;i<3;i++) //loop for number of lines
  {
      for(j=3;j>i;j--) // loop for printing _ 
      {
        printf(" ");
      }
      for(k=0;k<=i;k++) // loop for printing *_
      {
        printf("* ");
      }
      printf("\n");
  }
  getch();
}
```

So plz help me......

Comment: Am I the only one which is not seeing any identifiable pattern?

Comment: Post your code to [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<N;++i){
    printf("%*s", N-i-1, "");//field width specification
    for(j=0;j<=i;++j){
        printf("*");
        if(j<i)
            printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

---

```
#define N 3
...
char line[(N-1)+1+2*(N-1)]={0};//pre , *, "* "*(N-1)
int i,j,k;
for(k=0, i=N-1;k<N;i+=2,++k){
    line[i] = '*';
    for(j=k;j<=i;++j){
        putchar(line[j] ? line[j] : ' ');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: your 1st program isn't giving me the desired output but your second program is producing it.. thanxx for your help.... :) :D

Comment: @user3759158 ; Execution example (1) http://ideone.com/zCeNhw (2) http://ideone.com/r3E0Xr